# Can IPv6 be implemented on a mcf52259 demo board?

Tags: ipv6

I heard that there is a possibility of IPv4 being implemented on a [mc52259demo](http://www.freescale.com/webapp/sps/site/prod_summary.jsp?code=M52259DEMOKIT) coldfire board. Can IPv6 be implemented too? It is a Coldfire processor board developed by Freescale and it uses MQX OS.

Even [Embedded Access Inc](http://www.embedded-access.com/products.html) (as seen in [Mark's answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/11595/can-ipv6-be-implemented-on-a-mcf52259-demo-board/11618#11618)) does not provide IPv6 on the MCF52259demo board.

I am implementing this myself and not depending on any RTOS vendor's support, so the actual problem in implementation is this: What changes need to occur in the code in IPv6 from IPv4 that is to be loaded onto the board?

Comment: To have your question answered you should provide some context so that others may understand what are you talking about. Also pay attention to spelling. You ask about solving a problem but we don't know what problem you are talking about.

Comment: Agree with Jakub. From the context I assume you're working with an embedded system? It would help to know what exactly this demo board is (can you provide a link?) and what operating system it will be running. Right now it's not clear that your question is a programming question (are you implementing IPv6 yourself or are you trying to enable some RTOS vendor's IPv6 support?), so there's a good chance it could be closed if you can't explain what the programming problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the free RTOS from freescale doesn't support it though (that i know of).

[Here is one that does](http://www.embedded-access.com/products.html), probably are others as well.